# Intellij Spring Integration Diagram fails to detect connections via messaging template

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-integration

*Please Note : I am new to Spring Integration.*

I am writing a simple ETL flow using Spring integration where each stage of processing is connected to the next via simple *Direct Channels*.

In some stages there is a one to many relationship or event explosion happening i.e. an event containing a new file to be processed is passed to a consumer via a channel and the consumer is parsing the file. In these kind of cases I am not using a *service-activator* but opted to simply parse the file and send messages using a *MessagingTemplate* to the next stage via a different (or output) direct channel.

In this kind of scenario the **Spring Integration Diagram** in **Intellij** does not detect the connection between the file parsing stage and the output channel (via the messaging template).

While it is understandable that this is to be expected given the dependency is not direct, is there a different way I can change my setup so that this dependency does becomes visible in the 'Spring Integration diagram' in Intellij ?

I am using Intellij Ultimate Edition 2019.

Comment: The diagrams are built based on your Java annotations or XML Spring configuratoin. See corresponding post about the feature: [Spring and Spring Boot Improvements in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/07/spring-and-spring-boot-improvements-in-intellij-idea-2018-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct: as long as you use a `MessagingTemplate` by yourself you break a flow because it it based on the `input` and `output` channel options of the endpoints.

According your task it sounds like you need a `FileSplitter` and an `ExecutorChannel` to process each parsed line separately downstream.

See docs for more info:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#executor-channel

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#file-splitter